# Log in and reconnect to SignalR

Tags: asp.net, authentication, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to implement user sign-in using AJAX and display progress messages during that using SignalR. Unfortunately, SignalR doesn't like changing user identity, so I'm disconnecting and then reconnecting. However, I can't connect back for some reason -- it says "Unrecognized user identity. The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection."

To reconnect, I'm executing a client-side method, called from a Hub:

```
$.connection.reconnectingHub.client.reconnect = function () {
        $.connection.hub.stop();
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }
```

How do I do it properly?

Comment: Can post your code of hub ?

Comment: The Hub is empty, I'm calling the "reconnect" method using a HubContext object.